# Install problem MiKTeX under GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, miktex

Since around October 16 2022 we have problems with installing MiKTeX under GitHub Actions.
The error we get is:

```
Run ./miktexsetup_standalone --local-package-repository=C:/miktex-repository \
  ./miktexsetup_standalone --local-package-repository=C:/miktex-repository \
                --package-set=essential \
                --shared \
                install
  shell: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.EXE --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
initexmf.exe: The executed process did not succeed.
initexmf.exe: Data: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The procedure followed in GitHub Actions consists of a few steps:

## Step 1:

```
    - name: Download MikTex (Windows)
      run: |
        $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
        $maxAttempts=5;
        $attemptCount=0;
        Do {
          $attemptCount++;
          Try {
            $wc.DownloadFile("https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/miktexsetup-5.1-x64.zip","miktexsetup-5.1-x64.zip")
          } Catch [Exception] {
            Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
          }
        } while (((Test-Path "miktexsetup-5.1-x64.zip") -eq $false) -and ($attemptCount -le $maxAttempts))
      shell: pwsh
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

## Step 2:

```
    - name: Extract MikTex zip (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        unzip miktexsetup-5.1-x64.zip
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

## Step 3:

```
    - name: Download MikTex packages (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        ./miktexsetup_standalone --verbose \
                      --local-package-repository=C:/miktex-repository \
                      --remote-package-repository="https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/" \
                      --package-set=essential \
                      download
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

## Step 4 (the failing step):

```
    - name: Install MikTex packages (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        ./miktexsetup_standalone --local-package-repository=C:/miktex-repository \
                      --package-set=essential \
                      --shared \
                      install
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

## Step 5:

```
    - name: Setting MikTex paths (Windows)
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/" >> $GITHUB_PATH
        export PATH="/c/Program Files/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/:$PATH"

        echo "Configuring MiKTeX to install missing packages on the fly"
        initexmf --admin --verbose --set-config-value='[MPM]AutoInstall=1'
      if: matrix.config.os == 'windows-latest'
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem / what can be the problem?

Comment: Cross posted at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/1204

Comment: Created an issue from this https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on discussions in https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/1204 and https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1213 the solution is to replace the MiKTeX version's zip file

**from**:
miktexsetup-5.1-x64.zip

**to**:
miktexsetup-5.2.0+b8f430f-x64.zip

Answer (score 0):

Following GitHub workflow works for me:

```yaml
name: MiKTeX (Windows)
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  miktex:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install MiKTeX
        run: |
          choco install miktex --no-progress
          echo "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8
      - run: initexmf --admin --verbose --set-config-value=[MPM]AutoInstall=1
      - run: miktex --admin --verbose packages update-package-database
      - run: miktex --admin --verbose packages update
      - run: miktex --verbose packages update
      - run: miktex --admin --verbose packages install cm-super
      - run: miktex --admin --verbose fndb refresh
      - run: initexmf --admin --verbose --update-fndb
      - run: initexmf --admin --verbose --mklinks --force
      - run: updmap --admin
      - run: pdflatex example.tex
```

See it live at https://github.com/koppor/mwe-miktex/blob/main/.github/workflows/miktex-windows.yml.